# sharedAccessPolicyKey of service bus from stream analytics job template in azure template.json

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-lake, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub

How to get the value of service bus sharedAccessPolicyKey to streamanalytics job without using event hub, in template.json deployment.

I am doing the following `IOTHUB-->SAS-->SERVICEBUS-->LogicApp-->DLS` flow.
I am not using the `Eventhub` in my scenario.

Thanks,
Sathiyarajan M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the value of service bus sharedAccessPolicyKey to streamanalytics job without using event hub, in template.json deployment.

Please try to use [List Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-resource#listkeys) to get the key. The following code works fine on my side, please refer to it.

```
"[listKeys(concat(resourceId('Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces', parameters('servicebusnamespacename')),'/AuthorizationRules/RootManageSharedAccessKey'), '2015-08-01').primaryKey]"
```

[image]

*Note:* as far as I know, the above code call [this API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/namespaces#Namespaces_ListKeys) to get the Keys.